# Do spaceships have Earth vermin?

Tags: animals, space-exploration

Pests are always sneaking into cargo bins in one place and escaping into another place far away. Can somebody please name the first novel, comic or movie that depicts rats or other Earth vermin surreptitiously accompaning mankind in our science fictional forays into space? Is there an example of a space colony, starship, or starbase with non-human Earth descended pests?

Comment: I say no more than: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tribble

Comment: "The Rolling Stones" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones_(novel)# ) was 15 years earlier, but neither features *earth* vermin.

Comment: @bitmask That's the trouble with Iota Geminorum IV. Too many OoOooOooO's.

Comment: -0, I think this question might be too wide spread to give a good answer.

Comment: I like the question... There are lots of stories that ignore the issue of vermin going into space with man, it would be interesting to know what's the earliest story that addressed it.

Comment: Sorry, you may ignore my vote to close - I missed the fact that you were asking for the **first** instance on my first read-through.  The vote will dissipate in a few days.

Comment: Wiliam Tenn's The Men in the Walls http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Men_and_Monsters, 1968 offers an interesting twist on space vermin.

Comment: Then there is the Stainless Steel Rat. First apeared in 1957. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stainless_Steel_Rat :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. Bertram Chandler's "Giant Killer" has mutated smart [rats](http://www.magicdragon.com/UltimateSF/thisthat.html#bambi) infesting a spaceship. It was [first published](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45646) in October 1945 and has been reprinted many times. But I bet there's something earlier....

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's the earliest mention of vermin in space, but ["The Mote in God's Eye"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye) certainly has vermin: rats and other human pests, as well as Motie vermin (Brownies).

I can't check right now, but I'm pretty sure ["Downbelow Station"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downbelow_Station) and other Cherryh stories mention rats, and I'm also pretty sure some of Heinlein's stories mention rats.

Comment: BROWNIES were awesome! Waaaaaay better than Tribbles.

Comment: Doh! I meant *Watchmakers*.